# Special characters in Titanium Mobile JSON and Android

Tags: javascript, android, json, mobile, titanium

I have an application that send data to web service with json, and the asp.net receive the data and save in the SQL Server.
The application works well, but when i run on Android device, the special characters are saved wrong.

```js
exports.atuEmpreendimento = function(empCodigo, empNome, empCidade, empEstado, callback){
    var httpReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    httpReq.onload = function(e){
        callback(this.responseText);
    };
    httpReq.open('POST',Ti.App.URL + '/mobile/?a=atuEmpreendimento');
    httpReq.setRequestHeader("contentType","application/json; charset=utf-8");
    httpReq.setRequestHeader("dataType","json");
    empCidade = escape(empCidade);
    var params = {
        empCodigo: empCodigo,
        empNome: empNome,
        empCidade: empCidade,
        empEstado: empEstado
    };
    Ti.API.info(empCidade);
    httpReq.send(params);
    httpReq.onerror = function(data){
        alert(L('msgInternetError'));
    };
};
```

When I send for example: "São Gonçalo" the web service save "SÃ£o GonÃ§alo".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` in the **RESPONSE** headers? (Not in the request headers)